# Open multiple browser windows side-by-side in Python?

Tags: python

From python, I'm hoping to launch three chrome browser windows side-by-side. However, webbrowser seems to not have that advanced functionality.

Is there a way to do this in Python?

EDIT: I'm specifically looking for solutions on a mac.

Comment: use selenium web driver

Comment: IMO it will depend on OS you use. F.e. for Windows you use WinAPI (windows resizing etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
import webbrowser as wb

google = ('Google search:')
tabs = ['tab1', 'tab2', 'tab3'] #using this you can add more tabs
i = 0
while i < len(tabs):
    print (wb.open_new_tab('http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&q=%s' % google))
    i = i + 1
```

this will use your default browser(in this case  chrome)